# Count array result differences

Tags: php, arrays, merge, count, difference

I am trying to figure out how I count the difference, in **PHP** arrays results.

**I got this:**
3 different API Endpoints where I collect data from. I merge that data into arrays, with 15 results(*5 from each API*), in each array. I use a pagination to loop through the arrays. But if one of the API's return 0 results, my arrays become 10 long, instead of 15.

**My Question:**
Is there a way to count the API results from each endpoint, figure out if one/more endpoints dont respond with 5 results(*15 in total for all 3 endpoints*), and add it to the last endpoint/split the two others, and keep the results at 15, until there a no more results from all 3 endpoints?

**API Control:**
The endpoints are controlled with parameters.

> api.domain.com/sofas&per_page=5

> api.domain.com/chairs&per_page=5

> api.domain.com/tabels&per_page=5

I have no clue how to do this, so all help are taken with kisses and hugs.

---

**Edit:**
The pagination is not the problem. I will always, no matter what, max get 15 results back, in total. The problem is that it will go from showing 15 results to 13 results per page. In the case where both sofas and chairs has run out, will it only show 5 per page. Because the ?per_page parameter dont know that two of the endpoints is empty and will continue to return 5 results.

---

**Now with code:**

```
    //---------- Request Items --------------------------
// URL Parameters
$api_url_end        = str_replace(' ', '+', $params['q']) . '&page=' . $params['p'] . '&per_page=5';

// Endpoints
$api_url_sofas  = 'https://api.domain.com/sofas?name=' . $api_url_end;
$api_url_chairs         = 'https://api.domain.com/chairs?name=' . $api_url_end;
$api_url_tabels = 'https://api.domain.com/tabels?name=' . $api_url_end;

// Decode
$total_pages_sofas  = json_decode(file_get_contents($api_url_sofas), true);
$total_pages_chairs     = json_decode(file_get_contents($api_url_chairs), true);
$total_pages_tables     = json_decode(file_get_contents($api_url_tables), true);

//---------- Pagination Total --------------------------
$total = $total_pages_sofas['total'] + $total_pages_chairs['total'] + $total_pages_tabels['total'];

//---------- Decode Results --------------------------
$result_sofas   = json_decode(file_get_contents($api_url_sofas), true);
$result_chairs  = json_decode(file_get_contents($api_url_chairs), true); 
$result_tables = json_decode(file_get_contents($api_url_tables), true);

// Merge Results
$api_results = $result_sofas['data'], $result_chairs['data'], $result_tables['data']);


// Echo Result Lists
echo '<ol class="result-list">';

//---------- Foreach Result --------------------------
$rowCount = 0;
foreach($api_results as $result){

    // If Sofa
    if($result['sofa']){
        $rowCount++;
        echo 'Sofa';

    // If Chair
    }else if($result['chair']){
        $rowCount++;
        echo 'Chair';

    // If Table
    }else if($result['table']){
        $rowCount++;
        echo 'Tables';
    }
}

echo '</ol>';

// How many items to list per page
$limit = $rowCount;

// How many pages will there be
$pages = ceil($total / $limit);

// Calculate the offset for the query
$offset = ($page - 1)  * $limit;

// Some information to display to the user
$start = $offset + 1;
$end = min(($offset + $limit), $total);

//---------- Search Results Stats --------------------------
echo '<div class="result-stats">About ' . $start . '-' . $end . ' of ' . $total . ' results (<em>' . $execution_time_result . ' seconds</em>)</div>';

//---------- Pagination --------------------------         
// Build up the Previous page Link
$prevlink = ($page > 1) ? '<a href="' . $current_page_pnav . '&p=1" title="First page"><i class="fal fa-chevron-double-left"></i><em>First</em></a><a href="' . $current_page_pnav . '&p=' . ($page - 1) . '" title="Previous page"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i><em>Previous</em></a>' : '<span class="disabled"><i class="fal fa-chevron-left"></i></span><span class="disabled"><i class="fal fa-chevron-double-left"></i></span>';

// Build up the Next Page Link
$nextlink = ($page < $pages) ? '<a href="' . $current_page_pnav . '&p=' . ($page + 1) . '" title="Next page"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i><em>Next</em></a> <a href="' . $current_page_pnav . '&p=' . $pages . '" title="Last page"><i class="fal fa-chevron-double-right"></i><em>Last</em></a>' : '<span class="disabled"><i class="fal fa-chevron-right"></i></span><span class="disabled"><i class="fal fa-chevron-double-right"></i></span>';

// Check if more than 20 results
// If more than 20 results, hide the paging
if($total > 5){

    // Echo out the Paging
    echo '<section id="tmp-paging"><p>' . $prevlink . '<strong>Page ' . $page . ' of ' . $pages . '</strong>' . $nextlink . '</p></section>';
}
```

Comment: Sure `count($apiResult)` :)

Comment: So what happens if you get 3 results from sofas, 5 from chairs and 5 from tables?

Comment: @AlonEitan The pages in my pagination goes to 13 results per page, instead of 15.

Comment: Oh, I see, so the first comment should do the trick (I think)

Comment: The pagination is not the problem. I will always, no matter what, max get 15 results back, in total. The problem is that it will go from showing 15 results to 13 results per page. In the case where both sofas and chairs has run out, will it only show 5 per page. Because the ?per_page parameter dont know that two of the endpoints is empty and will continue to return 5 results.

Comment: Can you post the code.

Comment: Please show us your current code. Broadly speaking it should be possible to count the results from each api as you receive them but when and where you can do this depends on how you are receiving the data.

Comment: @AndrewHardiman Done :-)

Comment: @apokryfos Done :-)

Comment: Something `count($total_pages_sofas['data'])` should contain the number of results from the first API you can do the same for the other two. Also you don't need to run `file_get_contents` twice for each api. Once should be enough